# Select all files that do not have string between 2 other strings

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a set of files that i need to loop through and find all the files that does not have a specific string between 2 other specific strings. How can i do that?

I tried this but it didnt work:

```
grep -lri "\(stringA\).*\(?<!stringB\).*\(stringC\)" ./*.sql
```

EDIT:
the file could have structure as following:

```
StringA
StringB
StringA
StringC
```

all i want i s to know if there is any occurences where string A and stringC has no stringC in between.

Comment: stringA, stringC must be in the file?

Comment: yes, but there should be no stringB between them to comply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with the statement provided by the DreadPirateShawn:

```
stringA[^(?:stringB)]*stringC
```

I figured out that it is not a truly valid regex. This statement was excluding *every character in the given set* and not the full string. So I continued digging.

After some googling and testing the pattern, I came up with the following statement, that seems to fit my needs:

```
stringA\s*\t*(?:(?!stringB).)*\s*\t*stringC
```

This pattern matches *any text except the provided string* between 2 specified strings. It also takes into consideration whitespace characters.

There is more testing to be done, but it seems that this pattern perfectly fits my requirements

UPDATE: Here is a final version of the statement that seems to work for me:

```
grep -lriz "(set feedback on){0,}[ \t]*(?:(?!set feedback off).)*[ \t]*select sysdate from dual"  ./*.sql
```

Comment: I'm curious where mine failed. Can you provide the sample data that my regex didn't handle? I'd like to learn where I went awry.

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn: sure! Here is somewhat a requirement that i wrote to myself: Have(stringA)+AnyAmountOfText+DoNotHave(stringB)+AnyAmountOfText+Have(stringC). Basically, take any SQL script, add "set feedback on" & "select sysdate from dual" on a different lines and then add "set feedback off" in between. It didnt work me, so i ended up with the following statement: (see answer, i updated it)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is along the lines of:

```
grep "abc[^(?:def)]*ghi" ./testregex
```

That's based on a testregex file like so:

```
abcghiabc
abcdefghi
abcghi
```

The output will be:

```
$ grep "abc[^(?:def)]*ghi" ./testregex 
abcghiabc
abcghi
```

Mapped to your use-case, I'd wager this translates roughly to:

```
grep -lri "stringA[^(?:stringB)]*stringC" ./*.sql
```

Note that I've removed the ".*" between each string, since that will match the very string that you're attempting to exclude.

Update: The original question now calls out line breaks, so use grep's -z flag:

```
-z
```

> suppress newline at the end of line, subtituting it for null character. That is, grep knows where end of line is, but sees the input as one big line.

Thus:

```
grep -lriz "stringA[^(?:stringB)]*stringC" ./*.sql
```

When I first had to use this approach myself, I wrote up the following explanation...

> Specifically: I wanted to match "any character, any number of times,
>   non-greedy (so defer to subsequent explicit patterns), and NOT
>   MATCHING THE SEQUENCE />".
>
> The last part is what I'm writing to share: "not matching the sequence
>   />". This is the first time I've used character sequences combined
>   with "any character" logic.
>
> My target string:
>
> `<img class="photo" src="http://d3gqasl9vmjfd8.cloudfront.net/49c7a10a-4a45-4530-9564-d058f70b9e5e.png" alt="Iron or Gold" />`
>
> My first attempt:
>
> `<img.*?class="photo".*?src=".*?".*?/>`
>
> This worked in online regex testers, but failed for some reason within
>   my actual Java code. Through trial and error, I found that replacing
>   every ".*?" with "[^<>]*?" was successful. That is, instead of
>   "non-greedy matching of any character", I could use "non-greedy
>   matching of any character except < or >".
>
> But, I didn't want to use this, since I've seen alt text which
>   includes these characters. In my particular case, I wanted to use the
>   character sequence "/>" as the exclusion sequence -- once that
>   sequence was encountered, stop the "any character" matching.
>
> This brings me to my lesson:
>
> Part 1: Character sequences can be achieved using (?:regex). That is,
>   use the () parenthesis as normal for a character sequence, but prepend
>   with "?:" in order to prevent the sequence from being matched as a
>   target group. Ergo, "(?:/>)" would match "/>", while "(?:/>)*" would
>   match "/>/>/>/>".
>
> Part 2: Such character sequences can be used in the same manner as
>   single characters. That is, "[^(?:/>)]*?" will match any character
>   EXCEPT the sequence "/>", any number of times, non-greedy.
>
> That's pretty much it. The keywords for searching are "non-capturing
>   groups" and "negative lookahead|lookbehind", and the latter feature
>   goes much deeper than I've gone so far, with additional flags that I
>   don't yet grok. But the initial understanding gave me the tool I
>   needed for my immediate task, and it's a feature that I've wondered
>   about for awhile -- thus, I figured I'd share the basic introduction
>   in case any of you were curious about tucking it away in your toolset.

Comment: so will this match the pattern if i have other text between those strings, e.g. "stringA[bunch of text]stringB[bunch of text][stringC]?

Comment: @return_false: I thought it wouldn't, but when I tested it, it actually does. I guess I'll have to study study this one to understand why it works. +1 from me.

Comment: @DeadPirateShawn here is what i try: loop through the files and remove \n \r to make them inline, then 

    grep -lri "set feedback off[^\(?:set feedback on\)]*select sysdate from" ./*.sql | wc -l 

i have the file that will comply with this pattern, but wc - l returns 0 count.

Comment: I've added the "-z" flag to my answer to account for newlines. As for @Steiner, the trick is that "(?:stringB)" is effectively treated as a single character, so "[^(?:stringB)]*" is "any number of characters that are not equal to the undesired string-character" -- thus it matches any other text between strings A and C.

Comment: For some weird reason it was failing on the files that i modified to remove \n \r. worked with -z. Thanks!

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn: after playing around with this satement, I found out that it is not the valid RegEx to exclude the given string (maybe due to the grep versions difference?). Your statemnt will exclude every character in the given set and not the string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-L` option of `grep` to print all files which don't match and look for the specific combination of strings:

```
grep -Lri "\(stringA\).*\(stringB\).*\(stringC\)" ./*.sql
```

Comment: This will create some false positives (i.e. some files are matched that shouldn't be). It will, for example, match files that does not contain stringA or stringB. If you pipe it into a second grep, it should work though, something like: `grep -Lriz "\(stringA\).*\(stringB\).*\(stringC\)" ./*.sql | xargs grep -liz "\(stringA\).*\(stringC\)"`. The -z option was added (to both greps) since OP apparently wanted to match multilines.